# log4j aligned ConversionPattern

Tags: log4j, design-patterns, alignment

Is it possible to create a ConversionPattern in log4j as such

```
Some short Msg                    : [INFO] class date
Some very looooooooooooooong msg  : [INFO] class date
```

What I basically would like to achieve is that message is aligned to left and the rest of information starts after n characters, thus the rest is nicely aligned instead of

```
Some short Msg : [INFO] class date
Some very looooooooooooooong msg : [INFO] class date
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put a `-` in the pattern like:

```
%-50m   | [%p] %c{1} %d %n"/
```